# Delete a file from the partial string xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, string

im seeking for assistant.In my case i have file such as

1. RN150622103444544_pr.pdf
2. RN150622103444544_ID_GD.pdf
3. RN150622103444544_CA.xml

My question is how can i delete all the file only by referring the RN150622103444544.
Currently my code is deleting one by one.
Below are my sample code

```
-(void)deleteOldPdfs:(NSString *)proposal
{


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 if([fm fileExistsAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_pr_1.pdf",proposal]]])
{
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_pr_1.pdf",proposal]] error:&error];
}
    if([fm fileExistsAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_id_GD.pdf", proposal]]]){
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_id_GD.pdf", proposal]] error:&error];
    }
    if([fm fileExistsAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_CA.xml", proposal]]]){
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_CA.xml",proposal]] error:&error];
}
}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could put the unique suffixes in an array and then loop over the array.

Sample code (untested):

```
NSArray *suffixList = @[@"pr_1.pdf", @"id_GD.pdf", @"CA.xml"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

for (NSString *suffix in suffixList) {
    NSString *path = [FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",proposal, suffix]];
    if([fm fileExistsAtPath:path]){
        [fm removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }
}
```

Note: `paths` and `docmentsDirectory` were not used in the question code and are not included in the answer.

Comment: Hi zaph,how if i want delete just by looking at RN150622103444544 and ignore the type behind....can u assist me please...thank you

Comment: Use: `if (fileName hasPrefix:@"RN150622103444544")`